# JNDI Variable change, need for restart of the payara instance?

Tags: java, jndi, payara

Do I need to restart my payara instance after changing a JNDI variable to apply the changes in the application?

Or is there some kind of automatic reload mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a restart of the payara instance is needed if the JNDI variable is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to restart the whole payara server or domain, you just need to reload your web application that reads it.

If you look at your glassfish/payara web console and go to your Applications page, you can see a Reload option.  If you click on that for your app, it will essentially restart and it will read in the updated jndi value you just changed.

However if you have lots of web apps reading from the same jndi variable its probably easier just restarting your payara server.
[image]